# I am getting these error while running image on docker

Tags: docker

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 --name users-mysql --link mysql-standalone:mysql -d users-mysql
```

Unable to find image `users-mysql:latest` locally
docker:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for users-mysql, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Is users-mysql the image you built?

Comment: run `docker inspect mysql-standalone:mysql`

Answer (score 0):

The message means that it couldn't find the `users-mysql:latest` docker image in your local registry neither in the public one. Did you built the image by yourself or you want to use existing one from public repo?

If you want to use the image from public repo don't forget to use the whole name even with the prefix. List of images in public repo: https://hub.docker.com/search?q=users-mysql&type=image

If you built the image by yourself check by `docker image ls` the image is really present on your local. It could happen that it has a different tag than `latest` or you set some prefix there.